# Download specific resolution with youtube-dl

Tags: windows, python, youtube, youtube-dl

How to download video with specific video resolution, lets say Full HD with best audio and merge them together. I need a one line command in which you just can change the video resolution if choose to. Like `youtube-dl -f video=1080+bestaudio https://www.youtube.video123`, and then I could change the resolution if I want to. Also if that resolution is not available download should fail.

Comment: Related question on our sister site: [How to select video quality from youtube-dl?](https://askubuntu.com/q/486297/129094)

Comment: You might be looking for something like `youtube-dl -f 'best[height<=1080]'`.

Comment: The double quotes...

Comment: Yes but the problem is that there is a 1920x1080 video and I'm unable to download it with this method. It defaults to 1280x720.

Comment: "mp4[height=1080]+bestaudio" did it.